# Does firewall outbound rule apply for communication inside local computer

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall, outbound

On my machine there is a web application (let's call it **WebApp1**) hosted in IIS, and there is a windows services **Svc1** which will send request to the **WebApp1** as below, the **WebApp1** just handle the request and do NOT post any result back

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient {Timeout = 3 * 1000)};
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:58018/MyAction");
requestMessage.Headers.Add(tokenName, tokenValue);

var response = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
...
```

then I change the default outbound rule on the machine is set as **Blocked**, I want to know will this affect the 'communication' between **Svc1** and **WebApp1**? In another words, is the outbound rule only affect the communication to the outside computer or also applied for the communication inside the local computer?

Below is got from [msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd421709%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bkmk_Whatisanoutboundrule), but it does not tell too much detailed

> What is an outbound rule?
>
> Outbound rules explicitly allow, or explicitly block, network traffic
>   originating from the computer that matches the criteria in the rule.
>   For example, you can configure a rule to explicitly block outbound
>   traffic to a computer (by IP address) through the firewall, but allow
>   the same traffic for other computers.
>
> Because outbound traffic is
>   allowed by default, you typically use outbound rules to block network
>   traffic that you do not want. You can also configure the default
>   action that Windows Firewall with Advanced Security takes, whether
>   outbound connections are allowed or blocked, when no outbound rule
>   applies.

Comment: Why can't you take five minutes to try it and see? Create the rule, see if it interferes; if it does, and you don't want that, delete the rule. If you do it in your test environment, there's zero risk, and you'd have an answer by now.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, you are right, from what I tested the outbound rule does not block the communication between the Svc1 and WebApp1, but what I need is not only my test result but also an 'official' statements on this

Comment: *Official* from whom? Microsoft is the only one who can *officially* say so, and they're not going to do so here; this is not the *Microsoft Official Pronouncements Site*. They're going to do so in the MSDN documentation, which you have already.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree that Microsoft will not make statements here, but if somebody has invested on the similar issue and could provide findings or conclusions here, it will be helpful and I will very appreciate that (the 'offical' seems not be suitable in my previous comments and I did not get a more proper word, so forget about that)

Comment: *Outbound communications* means outside the boundaries of the computer. If both the web app and the service are on the same machine, the firewall does not apply. The firewall is applied at the boundary of the machine (the outbound port on the network interface). If you read your question title, it's clear - the *outbound rule* does not apply for **inside communications*, because there's nothing *outbound* involved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800527/does-a-firewall-on-a-machine-only-block-stuff-from-outside-the-machine-or-also-f/3800568#3800568

Comment: That refers to rules set up on the loopback port (127.0.0.1) with a rule set up for that IP address. None of what you asked refers to doing any of that, so I'm not sure what your link was designed to indicate (other than that you didn't read that linked question well enough). You're clearly not going to listen to what anyone has to say except whoever you've decided counts as *official*, and I'm apparently not one of them (even with more than 2 decades of experience dealing with Windows and Icurrently administer a Windows Active Domain with a dozen servers and nearly a hundred systems.

Comment: (continued) as well as having written two dozen large (one is 1MM LOC), but hey - what could I know? I'll leave you waiting for whoever you bless as being holy enough to bless whatever you're wanting to do. I'm out. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite at first I have to say thanks you for typing so many words and answer my question. But I am curious that how did you made the solution that 1. 'Why can't you take five minutes to try it and see?'  2.' you didn't read that linked question well enough' and 3. 'You're clearly not going to listen to what anyone has to say except whoever you've decided counts as official' , I will tell you that I post question here after I did the test and I read every sentence on each post. Yes, you are very very very experienced on so many fields, but I am not, so I need post question here

Comment: (continued) and I really curious that why your attitude is not so good at the first comment, just because I asked a 'stupid' question??? I just want to say nobody will have question if we know everything. You could just ignore the 'stupid' question, but please do not  try to criticism

Comment: No, it wasn't attitude, and I didn't say or imply it was a *stupid question*. It was a serious question about why you didn't just try it and see what was or was not affected, and if you'd just done what I suggested you'd have been done two days ago instead of still waiting. And my previous comments have directly addressed the question you're asking. I'm not sure why *you've* decided to get snippy here. I was trying to help you, but since apparently you're not interested in my help because I'm not **official** enough for you, I'll leave you be and not waste any more of my time trying to help.

Comment: Once more,  I post question here after I did the test (before you told me to do the test). Is that clear enough? The communication was not influenced on my test, **BUT** I still need some evidences (or reasons) to proven the test result, not just a test