# Couldn't get any response when sending request to Postman

Tags: rest, docker, postman

When I send a `Post` request to `Postman`, I get `Could not get any response`
 error. The call is something like the following:

```
https://localhost:8080/ProjectName/ClassName/MethodName
```

My colleague tries exactly the same endpoint and there is no problem for him. It seems that the problem is something with the settings on my laptop. I tried the endpoint with `Insomnia`. But I still get the same error.

In the meantime, when I have some calls which do not require port number, there is no problem. I have the problem just with the calls which require me to mention the port number directly.

I should also mention that I'm using `Docker` and when I try to set a remote debug for my project, I get an error `Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8080)`. I'm not sure if these problems are related. But I think there is something wrong with my port settings. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800111/how-to-choose-which-port-to-use-when-building-a-windows-service-windows-net

Comment: I've had similar things in the past - This might help or it might not. In the Postman settings, under `General`, try turning off the `SSL certificate verification` option.

Comment: @DannyDainton Thanks Danny. But unfortunately, it didn't help me.

Comment: Worth a try... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was a stupid mistake from me.
As I said, I'm using `Docker`. I had used `docker-compose.override.yml` and had defined the ports there. But I had named the file wrongly `docker-compose-override.yml` (using a dash line instead of dot). So, the ports were not set correctly.